# How to access NodeJS from another network

Tags: android, node.js, server, port

I have a NodeJS server that I'm currently working on in my machine. The OS is Windows 10.

I'm part of a small team of two and we are currently in a stage of development where i'm branching out to android app development and the other guy is making additional changes to the NodeJS server.

Thing is, when we gather and use the same network, I can successfully connect to the server being hosted in another computer via the app by using target computer's IP_address:port when making the HTTP request, but when we are "home-office-ing" we can't seem to be able to see or connect to the server being hosted in each other's machines.

Even by using the http://192.168.0.x:port ,address which works when we are connected in the same network, we can't access and get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when in different networks.

The port we are using to open the server is port 80, but we tried with port 3000 and forwarded it on the router, and still, it doesn't work

Is there a way to open up the server so it can be seen by a computer in an outside network?(I know that it will also be available for any other computer to see and interact with the server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use public IP address.

The most easiest solution is to rent a VPS with public IP address.
Just Google 'rent vps server' to find any hosting provider.

Comment: but is there anyway i can make my ip address public? Because in the end the server is probably going to be run in a in-home machine 24/7

Comment: it also would be easier to test new functionalities on the fly, without the need of having to deploy it every time

Comment: @ChristianW.A.Hess most of providers can give to you a public ip address for your own home machine. usually it costs about $2-5 per month.

Comment: @ChristianW.A.Hess just ask in call center. I don't know your provider.